# Batch file variable not comparable

Tags: batch-file

I want to use batch file to detect if it's not 1st and 16th day of the month.
My batch file is as below:

```
ECHO %date%
SET day=%date:~7,2%
IF [%day%] NEQ [16](IF [%day%] NEQ [01] (GOTO RESTART))

:RESTART
echo "STOP SERVICES"
echo "START SERVICES"
GOTO END

:END
pause
```

below is the result

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>ECHO Thu 12/17/2015
Thu 12/17/2015

C:\Users\user\Desktop>SET day=17

C:\Users\user\Desktop>IF [17] NEQ [16](IF [17] NEQ [01] (GOTO RESTART))
'[17]' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\user\Desktop>echo "STOP SERVICES"
"STOP SERVICES"

C:\Users\user\Desktop>echo "START SERVICES"
"START SERVICES"

C:\Users\user\Desktop>GOTO END

C:\Users\user\Desktop>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why the error below?:

'[17]' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

How do I make those variables comparable?

Comment: You are missing a space between the right bracket and left parentheses.

Comment: Question was put on hold because "a problem that can no longer be reproduced". Maybe because your date format is different from my.

Answer (score 1):

You should use EQU for numeral comparisons, and == for string comparisons. You also forgot to put GOTO END after your if, causing the script to always go to RESTART:

```
ECHO %date%
SET day=%date:~7,2%
IF not "%day%"=="16" (IF not "%day%"=="01" (GOTO RESTART))
GOTO END
:RESTART
echo "STOP SERVICES"
echo "START SERVICES"
GOTO END

:END
pause
```

Note that the way you get the day of the month is region-specific. For a region unspecific way use this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "day=%dt:~6,2%"
echo %date%
IF not "%day%"=="16" (IF not "%day%"=="01" (GOTO RESTART))
GOTO END
:RESTART
echo "STOP SERVICES"
echo "START SERVICES"
GOTO END

:END
pause
```

Comment: It's not numerical when day are 1 to 9, it will be 01 to 09.

Comment: @Pop If my answer solved your problem, you should consider clicking the check to the left of it so people searching on google for the same problem can find it. See [this](//stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for why this is important.